# installationFailureReason "NOT_FOUND" for app in testing track

Tags: android-management-api

Im having a hard time updating an app on a dedicated device in kiosk mode. After a system update I refreshed the policy by removing and readding the application object in two consecutive steps.

Now i get a installationFailureReason "NOT_FOUND" although it has been installed before.

The app is in an testing track. The application policy looks something like this:

```
{
      "packageName": "com.mypackage.name",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "accessibleTrackIds": [
        "[mytrackid]"
      ]
    }
```

Nothing special, and as I said, it worked before... but now i get this status:

```
 "nonComplianceDetails": [
    {
      "settingName": "applications",
      "nonComplianceReason": "APP_NOT_INSTALLED",
      "packageName": "my.package.name",
      "installationFailureReason": "NOT_FOUND"
    }
   ]
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: PS: Before the wipe I tried to set the "minimumVersionCode" of my app, only to get a 501 Internal Server Error from the android-management-api. So it seems like there is something broken here...

Answer (score 0):

There are just a couple of reasons why you’d receive a nonComplianceDetail value of NOT_FOUND for a private app:

1. App is not available to that enterprise ([help doc](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/9495634)). Check that the device is enrolled to the same enterprise as it was before. This seems like the most likely culprit in this case.
2. App track is not available to to that enterprise - make sure to add it to that specific test track ([help doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334)), or the app track ID in the policy is not the correct value.
3. App is no longer available in the Play Store - check that it is still published.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: The part after the question is link-only and not considered an answer either.